# Setting AUTO_INCREMENT format as "date/Num"

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

this is my first ques here so please forgive me for any mistakes.....

What i want to do is to set the Auto_increment option in MySQL database so that it starts counting from specific format such as  :

**date/number**

for eample: **2011-06-01/0001    ,
            2011-06-01/0002      ,
            .
            .
            .
            2011-06-02/0001      ,
            2011-06-02/0002**

```
        ...and so on
```

hope i make my problem clear, and thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's not possible.  However, you can emulate it using an INSERT trigger.  I don't have access to MySQL right now, but hopefully that will give you an idea of how to do it.  If I have time later, maybe I'll put example code together for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a table in this way

```
create table test (
id int(4) zerofill auto_increment,
mydate date,
primary key (mydate,id)
);

insert into test (mydate) 
values 
('2011-06-01'),
('2011-06-02'),
('2011-06-02'),
('2011-06-01'),
('2011-06-01'),
('2011-06-03');



mysql> select * from test;
+------+------------+
| id   | mydate     |
+------+------------+
| 0001 | 2011-06-01 |
| 0002 | 2011-06-01 |
| 0003 | 2011-06-01 |
| 0001 | 2011-06-02 |
| 0002 | 2011-06-02 |
| 0001 | 2011-06-03 |
+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I misunderstood your question. :(

Comment: This looks good but it limits your engine choice to myISAM, if you wanted innoDB you'd have to use triggers. There is no reason to store combined date/num in one column anyway and you can just concat them in select.

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp with microsecond support? like

```
CREATE table t (
    f1 TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_DATETIME
);
```

and a row numbered select:

```
SET @rownum : = 0
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS num, t.*
  FROM t
 WHERE DATE(t.f1) = '2011-01-01'
```